# Searching Multiple Vectors

Tags: c++

I have 4 vectors with about 45,000 records each right now. Looking for an efficient method to run through these 4 vectors and output how many times it matches the users input. Data needs to match on the same index of each vector.

Multiple for loops? Vector find?

Thanks!

Comment: Binary search?? If they are sorted of course.

Comment: are the vectors sorted?

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of what's inside the vectors and what the user input to search for to help illustrate?

Comment: Just sort them. And run binary search.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without more information. Is the input data 4 records, each record corresponding to one of the vectors? How many times are you expecting to do this? Would it be worth loading the data into another data structure if it sped up subsequent searches.

Comment: @progenhard If you sort then how do you meet the match on the same index of each vector requirement?

Comment: @AdeMiller You save the original index.

Comment: @AdeMiller 

The user inputs the 4 records only once per runtime. Their data is in correspondence to each vector.

Comment: @AdeMiller You can tweak you're binary search NO, it should actually show all the indexes of the same value if you coded it correctly.

Comment: @Rob Are all the vectors in relation to each other by index?

Comment: @progenhard. yes, they are all in relation to each other

Answer (score 1):

If the elements need to match at the same location, it seems that a `std::find()` or `std::find_if()` combined with a check for the other vectors at the position is a reasonable approach:

```
std::vector<A> a(...);
std::vector<B> b(...);
std::vector<C> c(...);
std::vector<D> d(...);

std::size_t match(0);
for (auto it = a.begin(), end = a.end(); it != end; ) {
    it = std::find_if(it, end, conditionA));
    if (it != end) {
        if (conditionB[it - a.begin()]
         && conditionC[it - a.begin()]
         && conditionD[it - a.begin()]) {
            ++match;
        }
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I got from description is that, you have 4 vectors and lots of user data, you need to find out how many of times it matches with vectors at same index
so here goes the code ( i am writing a c++4.3.2 code)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<typeT>a;  
    vector<typeT>b;
    vector<typeT>c;
    vector<typeT>d;
    vector<typeT>matched;
    /*i am assuming you have initialized a,b,c and d;
    now we are going to do pre-calculation for matching user data and store
    that in vector matched */
    int minsize=min(a.size(),b.size(),c.size(),d.size());
    for(int i=0;i<minsize;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==b[i]&&b[i]==c[i]&&c[i]==d[i])matched.push_back(a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this was the precalculation part. now next depend on data type you are using, Use binary search with little bit of extra counting or using a better data structure which stores a pair(value,recurrence) and then applying binary search. 
Time complexity will be O(n+n*log(n)+m*log(n)) where n is `minsize` in code and m is number of user input

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would have a couple of methods to maintain your database(vectors).

Essentially, do a [QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) to start out with.

Then ever so often consistently run a [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) (Faster then QuickSort for partially sorted lists)

Then just run [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on those vectors.

---

### edit:

I think a better way to store this is instead of using multiple vectors per entry. Have one class vector that stores all the values. (your current vectors)

```
class entry { 

public: 
      variable data1;
      variable data2;
      variable data3;
      variable data4;
}
```

Make this into a single vector. Then use my method I described above to sort through these vectors.

You will have to sort through by what type of data it is first. Then after call binary search on that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lookup table for the vector with `std::unordered_multimap` in `O(n)`. Then you can use `unordered_multimap::count()` to get the number of times the item appears in the vector and `unordered_multimap::equal_range()` to get the indices of the items inside your vector.

```
std::vector<std::string> a = {"ab", "ba", "ca", "ab", "bc", "ba"};
std::vector<std::string> b = {"fg", "fg", "ba", "eg", "gf", "ge"};
std::vector<std::string> c = {"pq", "qa", "ba", "fg", "de", "gf"};

std::unordered_multimap<std::string,int> lookup_table;

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    lookup_table.insert(std::make_pair(a[i], i));
    lookup_table.insert(std::make_pair(b[i], i));
    lookup_table.insert(std::make_pair(c[i], i));
}

// count
std::string userinput;
std::cin >> userinput;
int count = lookup_table.count(userinput);
std::cout << userinput << " shows up " << count << " times" << std::endl;

// print all the places where the key shows up
auto range = lookup_table.equal_range(userinput);
for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; it++) {
    int ind = it->second;
    std::cout << " " << it->second << " " 
        << a[ind] << " " 
        << b[ind] << " " 
        << c[ind] << std::endl;
}
```

This will be the most efficient if you will be searching the lookup table many items. If you only need to search one time, then Dietmar Kühl's approach would be most efficient.